# Input number aceitar ponto no firefox

Tags: formulário, input, firefox

podem me ajudar?

Tenho este input number que deve aceitar valores em decimal. As pessoas preenchem o decimal com ponto (.) e não com vírgula (,)

Em todos os navegadores funciona muito bem, EXCETO no firefox que é o nosso navegador padrão. (Firefox só está permitindo (,) e não (.))

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Procurei em vários sites (inclusive aqui no stackoverflow) e diversos métodos, a única forma que funcionou foi deixar o input como text e aplicar uma mascara com js convertendo os (.) em (,) evitando assim a dúvida ou o erro noob do usuário.

Tenho como permitir que o firefox aceite (.) no input number? Alguém sabe?
Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tudo bem!! Consegui uma solução bem mais simples usando:

< html lang="en" >

Desta forma o navegador interpreta o site com a linguagem que desejo, assim o ponto (.) começa a ser aceito!!! Grandes Abraços!!!

Comment: Sim, é uma boa saída.

Answer (score 1):

Nota: Qualquer número é um valor aceitável, desde que seja um número de ponto flutuante válido (ou seja, não NaN ou Infinity).

"1.0" é diferente "1,0" tem que ver como seu navegador trata ponto flutuante;

[Separador decimal](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separador_decimal) têm países que representa com  ",", ex: R$; e países que representam com  "." ex: $;

para aceitar "1.0" só que depende da localidade do seu navegador ele vai transformar para "1,0".

```
<input type="number" placeholder="1.0" step="0.01" min="0" max="10">
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <input type="number" placeholder="1.0" step="0.01" min="0" max="10">
</body>
</html>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/number

> Curiosidade: Mesmo que você tente forçar usando **toLocaleString()** o
>   **input "number"** segue a característica da localidade do browser;

```js
var number = 3.5;
document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = number.toFixed(2).toLocaleString('en-US');
console.log(number.toLocaleString());
```

```html
<html>
<body>
   <input type="number">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo, Pelo que entendi, então não há muito o que fazer. É uma questão de qual navegador estou usando. Se quero forçar a utilização do (.) tenho que configurar um campo texto com mascara e depois dar as devidas precauções a este campo para somente receber valores inteiros.

Comment: @ShBr sim é isso ai!

Comment: Olá pessoal, tudo bem!! Consegui uma solução bem mais simples usando <html lang="en">, desta forma, o navegador interpreta o site com a linguagem que desejo, assim o (.) começa a ser aceito!!! Grandes Abraços!!!